# Question about Tor browser and whether if it routes all of my computer's network traffic through the Tor network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration

I just downloaded Tor browser. Just to be sure: 
The Tor services are only applied to the Tor browser's network traffic, right?

Or does all network traffic coming to and from my computer goes through those services when I run the Tor browser? Say for example, I run Microsoft Edge or any other browsers, will their traffic also goes through the Tor network too?

I might not fully understand how this works. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: If you wish to use an operating system where all your traffic goes through Tor, consider using [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Only your internet surfing through the Tor browser is "protected" by using the Tor network, not the system (Operating System).

You can install the Tor service along with Obfsproxy and configure your system to route your network connections through the Tor port (usually 9050) however it requires some set up and configuration through Command Prompt/Terminal etc.